# xamarin.forms devexpress grid selected row

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid, devexpress

I am using the GridControl from devexpress in my Xamarin.Forms.  When the page is first displayed it has the first row selected automatically.  How can I change this so no row is selected?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the documentation directly you can find your answer:

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xamarin/CustomDocument12264

It seems you need to set the `SelectedRowHandle` property to change the selected row.

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xamarin/DevExpressMobileDataGridGridControl_SelectedRowHandletopic

Comment: I tried setting the SelectedRowHandle property to a 0 and to a -1 and it still keeps the first item in the grid selected.

Comment: 0 would refer to the first Data row. So that will not work. Secondly -1 might refer to the first Data row grouping. You can view this notes here: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xamarin/CustomDocument12287

Comment: Still unable to get this to work.  What a pain for something simple.

Comment: I know this question is old, but I have this same problem and a similar problem.  On one grid, I want nothing selected and on another, i want a specific row selected.  In both cases, the grid defaults to having the first row selected.  I have SelectedRowHandle bound to a property in my view model and I set it to a valid value.  Then with a breakpoint I can see that property get set to my value and then immediately hit again and get set to 0.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!